# python tkinter not display image in label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python.I have tried a code on how to display Texbox,image and button.But the **image not displays**
Please rectify my code to display the image!

My code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
            def __init__(self,parent):
                Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
                self.button2()
                self.text()
                self.image()
            def button2(self):
                button2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text = "hello")
                button2.grid(column=5,row=7)
            def text(self):
                text = Tkinter.Text(self, height=3, width=31) 
                text.grid(column=1,row=3)
                text.insert(END, "Wiilliam Skakespeare")

            def image(self):
                logo = PhotoImage(file="linux.gif")
                w1 = Tkinter.Label(self, image=logo)
                w1.grid(column=5,row=7)

app = myproject(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the PhotoImage as a class variable so the reference can stay in memory. The following method for `image()` should work:

```
def image(self):
    self.logo = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="linux.gif")
    w1 = Tkinter.Label(self, image=self.logo)
    w1.grid(column=5,row=7)
```

This page provides a more in-depth explanation: [Effbot PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). Specifically this section:

> **Note:** When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g.
>   when you return from a function which stored an image in a local
>   variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a
>   Tkinter widget.

To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object.